# How to test a class with a very complex constructor?

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have inherited some code which has some very complicated initialization in the constructor that depends on a very complex environment.

I only want to be able to test some functionality therefore just need an empty object, for example one which would have been generated by the default constructor, however the default constructor has been overwritten by some very complex stuff.

I do not have the ability to touch the source code therefore I just need the empty object to be able to call it's functions and test with.

How would I do this? I've looked at mocking but I can't seem to get the actual functionality of the class into the mock object.

UPDATE #1: Example to try to clarify what I'm asking

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, lots_of_stuff):
    lotsofthingsbeingdone()

class Bar(Foo):
  def core_functionality(self, something):
    val =  does_something_important(something)
    return val
```

I want to test core_functionality(). I want to feed it "something" and ensure that the val meets my expectation of what it should be.

Comment: If the things you want to test could be tested without a truly constructed object, why not just pull them off the class entirely and into helper functions, then test those?

Comment: Oh - "I do not have the ability to touch the source code" - I'm not sure you can really say you inherited it in that case, since you don't appear to have the ability or duty to maintain it, but that would interfere with any refactoring.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I can get by by just unit-testing some parts but there is some core functionality I would like to test that I can't really do outside of a dedicated test environment that would provide all of the files that the constructor requires. Because there's a nasty inheritance hierarchy at play I can't extract things without some serious refactoring or rewriting.

Moving past duty, is there a way to just get an empty object so I can test the complicated functionality without having to petition for a rewrite?

Comment: Are you testing the class, or a consumer of the class? What does *"can't seem to get the actual functionality"* mean? If you're mocking it out, you shouldn't want the actual functionality. Please give a less abstract example.

Comment: @user3325789: Was Bar supposed to inherit from Foo in that example?

Comment: sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow, updated the original post instead as comments seem to be limiting.

Comment: It seems like `core_functionality` should simply *not be an instance method at all*. Make it `@staticmethod` then you can call it on the class (`Bar.core_functionality(something)`) and `__init__` never gets called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this wisely. Don't make the legacy mess bigger:

```
# No constructors executed.
empty_object = object.__new__(YourClass)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved my problem! Will be very judicious!